# jQuery .on() and .not()

Tags: jquery

**html**

```
<li class="feed">
    <a data-uid="15" data-fid="23" href="http://domain">
        <img src="imageurl.com" class="favicon">
        <span>Website Title</span>
        <span class="options">delete</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).on('click', '.col-l .feed a', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //do something
});

$('.options').click(function(){
    var fid = $(this).parent().attr('data-fid');
    var uid = $(this).parent().attr('data-uid');
    console.log(fid);
    console.log(uid);
});
```

Whenever I click `delete` the jQuery `.on` runs as well as the `.options`. Is there a way that if `.options` is clicked it will ignore the `.on()` function?

I tried `$(document).on('click', '.col-l .feed a:not(.options)', function(e){` but to no success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you just need to stop the `.options` click from propagating up the DOM tree. For example (you'll also need to add `preventDefault` to the event too):

```
$(document).on('click', '.col-l .feed a', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //do something
});

$('.options').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    var fid = $(this).parent().attr('data-fid');
    var uid = $(this).parent().attr('data-uid');
    console.log(fid);
    console.log(uid);
});
```

Here's a [<kbd>jsFiddle demo</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/8vp4x/)